# Google Maps markers ontop of each other

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

So I have a probably not so unique scenario. The simplest way to explain it is a google map with all 50 US states, each state will have two markers. The markers are both driven by the same lat/long value. The problem Im having is that the markers are rendering ontop of one another. I somehow need to have them render next to one another or offset so that I can see both. The problem is how do I get it to not overlap into another state.

I saw some really neat "spider" functionality where it renders one marker and then if you click on it the others fan out, but the website was in another language.

I am going to try and use the following library.

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

The problem with the above implementation is that I am using a combination of KML and google maps client-side. I dont see a way to implement that for the kml markers

Comment: Is there a code question in there?

Comment: Sure, what code will allow me to shift the kml markers.

Comment: What does _your_ code and KML look like?  If the KML isn't too complex (2 markers per state is pretty simple), you could investigate using a third party KML parser, like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) with the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.

Comment: I saw in another post on stackoverflow about someone using a parser which would eventually cause the kml markers to render with native client-side javascript. Its not that my KML is complex, but I am using KML because there will potentially be a few thousand markers(maybe 6k) at any given time. And the first implementation of this with only client-side rendering of markers was slowwwww, which is why I switched to JAK Library->KML

Comment: 6K is a lot more than 2 per state, with a third party KML parser, complex KML does have performance issues.  Would you have the KML file with the 6K markers available somewhere?  I'm curious to see how long it takes to render, and whether using a MarkerClusterer helps any.

Comment: Ah yeah, eventually it wont just be stats it will be other granularity like zipcode or county. You can actually get the zip code boundry KML from google fusion tables from this link; https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1182141?hl=en The fusion table can be downloaded as a kml

Comment: Are you asking about markers or polygons? I know about the zipcode data - [zipcode labels using FusionTable data](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html)

Comment: Ops. I meant markers. I am using <Placemark> with Icons.

Comment: This [map displays ~ 220 markers with geoxml3 and MarkerClusterer}(http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/tanagerproductions_testmapA.html), if you have data (which is what I was looking for), I would be interested in your case with 6K markers.

Comment: Yeah let me see if I can generate some kml real quick.

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_markerClusterer_linkto.html?filename=zipcodes1pt.kml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) project on GitHub will probably accomplish what you need.

Otherwise you can play around with the Marker's `icon` property. The `icon` can accept a `Symbol` which has and anchor that can be shifted from the default location (0,0).

Symbol documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol

Comment: Yeah I did see that unfortunately the project I am working on is using both KML and google api. The KML is rendering 2 markers for each lat/long, which are the markers overlapping one another. The Marker Spiderfier looks like a great library however will not meet my needs. I will check out the icon property. Thanks!!